# Upgrade TinyMce 3.x to TinyMce 4.x

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

Currently I am working on TinyMce Upgrade for my application I found that in 4.0.16 Upgrade paste event is not there.

```
TinyMce 3.x
 // Force Paste-as-Plain-Text
 ed.onPaste.add(function(ed, e, o) {
   // Logic Here 
 });
```

I am looking this event in 4.0.16 but It seems to me doesn't exist any more. Please help me out here.

Comment: some plugins have been removed from 4x series as mentioned here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x

Comment: Maybe it's .on('paste' ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I have to update text in another div and this is what I came up with.

```
ed.on('change', function(e){
    var tinymceText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    alert(tinymceText);
});
```